# ¿Cómo borrar widgets y la información contenida dentro de ellos?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, interfaz-gráfica

***¡Hola Comunidad!***

Tengo una GUI con tkinter en la que se deberán ingresar dos (2) valores para realizar una operación (sumar dichos valores). Estos datos, que deberán ser ingresados por el usuario, se encuentran en un contenedor o *Frame* llamado `sumar_fm`.

El objetivo es que, una vez realizada la operación, se empaquete otro widget de tipo `tk.Button`, que borre o elimine a `sumar_fm` y a los widgets asociados a este. Luego que se realice esta "limpieza", el usuario debería poder tener la opción de volver a ingresar valores para realizar una nueva operación. Para ello, añadí un botón que permitiera volver a recuperar a `sumar_fm` y, en cierto modo, se recupera solo que la información de la operación anterior también lo hace.

**Observaciones:**

- Los widgets fueron empaquetados mediante el método `grid()`
- Los widgets fueron eliminados mediante el método `grid_remove()`

**El código es:**

```
import tkinter as tk

class App:

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()

        fm = tk.Frame(self.root)  # Contenedor principal
        fm.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

        sumar_fm = tk.Frame(fm)  # Contenedor de los datos para la suma
        sumar_fm.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=10)

        # Textos para que el usuario se ubique
        tk.Label(sumar_fm, text='Valor 1:').grid(row=0, column=0)
        tk.Label(sumar_fm, text='Valor 2:').grid(row=1, column=0)
        tk.Label(sumar_fm, text='Resultado:').grid(row=2, column=0)

        # Variables involucradas en el proceso
        valor1 = tk.IntVar()
        valor2 = tk.IntVar()
        resul = tk.IntVar()

        # Función para realizar la suma
        def sumar(): 
            resul.set(valor1.get() + valor2.get())

            # Mensaje que anuncia que se ha realizado el proceso
            tk.Label(sumar_fm, text='(Se ha realizado la suma)'
                ).grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=2)

            # Enpaquetado del botón para "Borrar"
            borrar_btn.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='nsew')

        # Función que borrará todos los widgets donde se realizó la suma
        def borrar():
            sumar_fm.grid_remove()
            sumar_btn.grid_remove()
            borrar_btn.grid_remove()
            nueva_suma_btn.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky='nsew')

        # Función para volver a ingresar valores
        def nueva_suma():
            sumar_fm.grid()
            sumar_btn.grid()
            nueva_suma_btn.grid_remove()

        tk.Entry(sumar_fm, textvariable=valor1
            ).grid(row=0, column=1)
        tk.Entry(sumar_fm, textvariable=valor2
            ).grid(row=1, column=1)
        tk.Entry(sumar_fm, textvariable=resul, state='readonly'
            ).grid(row=2, column=1)

        sumar_btn = tk.Button(fm, text='¡Sumar!', command=sumar)
        sumar_btn.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='nsew')

        borrar_btn = tk.Button(fm, text='Borrar widgets y su contenido', command=borrar)

        nueva_suma_btn = tk.Button(fm, text='Nueva suma', command=nueva_suma)

    def mainloop(self):
        self.root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ejemplo = App()
    ejemplo.mainloop()
```

Lo lógico sería que, cuando el usuario borre los widgets y luego seleccione el botón para realizar una nueva suma, se recuperen los widgets donde deberá ingresar los nuevos valores, pero, de la misma forma como se mostraron en la primera operación.

Me abstuve de crear variables para cada `tk.Label` y `tk.Entry` a modo de optimizar recursos, ya que encontrar una solución a este problema podría implementarse en aplicaciones que contengan mayor cantidad de variables.

***¡Gracias por sus comentarios y/o sugerencias!***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El método `grid_remove` no elimina los widgets, solo los oculta, manteniendo la configuración del `grid` (`column`, `row`, etc). Cuando vuelves a usar `grid` simplemente se vuelven a mostrar, pero los objetos son los mismos, con sus mismos atributos.

Es más, dado que los entries están asociados a variables (`IntVar`) y éstas siguen con el mismo valor, aún destruyéndolos y creando otros, si los vuelves a asociar a las misma variables el resultado anterior se mantendría.

La solución pasa por:

- Asignar cero (0) o una cadena vacía (`""`), dependiendo de que prefieras que se muestre en el `Entry` al iniciar (un 0 o vacío), a las tres `IntVar` en `borrar()`.
- En `sumar()` no crear el label con la información, se debe crear globalmente, asignado a una variable, pero sin posicionarlo.
- En `sumar()` usas `grid` para posicionar el label con la información.
- En `borrar()` usad el método `grid_remove` del label con la información para ocultarlo.

Adicionalmente, podemos resetear el foco, dado que el cursor aparcera en el último `Entry` en el que se ingresó algo.

---

```
import tkinter as tk


class App:

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()

        fm = tk.Frame(self.root)  # Contenedor principal
        fm.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

        sumar_fm = tk.Frame(fm)  # Contenedor de los datos para la suma
        sumar_fm.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=10)

        # Textos para que el usuario se ubique
        tk.Label(sumar_fm, text='Valor 1:').grid(row=0, column=0)
        tk.Label(sumar_fm, text='Valor 2:').grid(row=1, column=0)
        tk.Label(sumar_fm, text='Resultado:').grid(row=2, column=0)

        # Variables involucradas en el proceso
        valor1 = tk.IntVar()
        valor2 = tk.IntVar()
        resul = tk.IntVar()

        # Función para realizar la suma
        def sumar(): 
            resul.set(valor1.get() + valor2.get())
            # Mostramos el label para anunciar que se ha realizado el proceso
            info_label.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=2)
            # Enpaquetado del botón para "Borrar"
            borrar_btn.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='nsew')

        # Función que borrará todos los widgets donde se realizó la suma
        def borrar():
            sumar_fm.grid_remove()
            sumar_btn.grid_remove()
            borrar_btn.grid_remove()
            # Ocultamos el label
            info_label.grid_remove()
            # Asignamos 0 a las IntVars
            valor1.set(0)
            valor2.set(0)
            resul.set(0)
            # Reseteamos el foco
            self.root.focus()

            nueva_suma_btn.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky='nsew')

        # Función para volver a ingresar valores
        def nueva_suma():
            sumar_fm.grid()
            sumar_btn.grid()
            nueva_suma_btn.grid_remove()

        tk.Entry(sumar_fm, textvariable=valor1
            ).grid(row=0, column=1)
        tk.Entry(sumar_fm, textvariable=valor2
            ).grid(row=1, column=1)
        tk.Entry(sumar_fm, textvariable=resul, state='readonly'
            ).grid(row=2, column=1)

        sumar_btn = tk.Button(fm, text='¡Sumar!', command=sumar)
        sumar_btn.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='nsew')

        # Label para informar del estado del proceso
        info_label = tk.Label(
            sumar_fm, text='(Se ha realizado la suma)'
            )

        borrar_btn = tk.Button(fm, text='Borrar widgets y su contenido', command=borrar)

        nueva_suma_btn = tk.Button(fm, text='Nueva suma', command=nueva_suma)

    def mainloop(self):
        self.root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ejemplo = App()
    ejemplo.mainloop()
```